# Extracting nested python dictionaries in C

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, nested, python-c-api

How can access nested dictionaries passed from Python (through `scipy.weave`) to C?

I am developing some complex code which requires interfacing Python code with C code. The python/`scipy.weave` code passes to the C interface a nested dictionary, like:

```
nested_dict = {'key1': dict_1, 'key2': dict_2, ...}
```

where `dict_1,dict_2,...` are dictionaries themselves, like:

```
dict_1 = {'kd1': val1, ...}
```

Say I want to access `val1` in `kd1` of `dict_1`. The `scipy.weave` code calls the C function `myfunc(PyObject* nested_dict)` where:

```
void myfunc(PyObject* nested_dict){
    PyObject* dict1 = PyDict_GetItemString(nested_dict,"key1");
    double val1 = PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(PyDict_GetItemString(dict1,"kd1"));
}
```

Unfortunately this miserably crashes on the second line. And I cannot understand why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Maurizio

Comment: Where is your error checking?

Comment: Good point. I did some more error checking. I was passing a wrong data structure. The above code is correct.

Comment: Nonetheless you should add some error checking to the code (e.g. returning immediately if any return value is `NULL`).

Comment: Thanks. I will do it indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It was crashing because the nested dictionary I was passing did not have the key `key1`. A simple error checking as suggested by Ignacio in the comments, i.e.

```
PyObject * dict_1 = PyDict_GetItemString(nested_dict,"key1");
if(dict_1==NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "key1 is not a dictionary key\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

helped to identify the bug. Otherwise the code written above fulfills its purpose.

Comment: Note that `exit(-1);` is *not* in fact the thing you should be doing (nor should you need to print, but that is a separate issue); you should `return NULL;` after doing relevant cleanup so that the exception that was set by the API can be thrown to the caller.